# Can the tif images be displayed directly in Android studio?

Tags: android, image-processing

`Hello everyone, I'm  here again.
I was given a task to load an image in **.tif file format** in **android studio** and then do a method of image tranformation (python code to handle image tranformation, such as gabor filter/transformation).

My problem: The android studio phone first has to load the .tif image from the real phone one imageview to display it in the app.

I have a question,
**do .tif images really show up properly on the phone screen, because I can't see the .tif images on the screen?**

what I used
Image transformation libry:
https://github.com/Beyka/Android-TiffBitmapFactory
python code run in Android Studio:
https://github.com/chaquo/chaquopy

```
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat;
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.Manifest;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.ParcelFileDescriptor;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.chaquo.python.PyObject;
import com.chaquo.python.Python;
import com.chaquo.python.android.AndroidPlatform;

import org.beyka.tiffbitmapfactory.TiffBitmapFactory;

import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
```

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView textView8;

    //private static final int Read_Permission= 101;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button gallery = findViewById(R.id.gallery);
        gallery.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
               startActivityForResult(intent,3);
            }
        });


        /*if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, Read_Permission);
        }
 */





        textView8 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);

        if(!Python.isStarted()){
            Python.start(new AndroidPlatform(this));
        }

        Python py = Python.getInstance();
        PyObject pyobj = py.getModule("hello");
        // give python script name
        // now call this function
        PyObject obj = pyobj.callAttr("main");
        // now set return text to textview
        textView8.setText(obj.toString());



    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null){
            try {

                // from the Beyla original code
                ParcelFileDescriptor parcelFileDescriptor = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(data.getData(), "r");
                Bitmap bmp = TiffBitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(parcelFileDescriptor.getFd());

                ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bmp);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
           // Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
           // ImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.imageView);
           // imageView.setImageURI(selectedImage);
        }
    }

}
```

And the activity_main-xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MissingClass">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="250dp"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="80dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="194dp"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/gallery"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Pick Image"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="125dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="556dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView8"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.436"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/pick"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.2"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

```
`
```

Comment: Android does not natively support TIFF: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats?hl=en#image-formats. You may need to find a TIFF library.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, what I saw on Google is true !